# R: row index list from list of column values?

Tags: r, indexing, row

In R, how do I index a list of values from one R column based on a specified list of values from another column?

I know how to select and modify specific row numbers, e.g.:

```
> foo=data.frame(a=100*1:5,b=LETTERS[5:1])
> foo
    a b
1 100 E
2 200 D
3 300 C
4 400 B
5 500 A
> foo$a[c(1,3,5)]= foo$a[c(1,3,5)] + c(3,2,1)
> foo
    a b
1 103 E
2 200 D
3 302 C
4 400 B
5 501 A
```

But what if I instead want to select and modify the rows with the 'b' values "A", "E", and "C"?  I thought `which` might be the correct tool, but the best I've been able to come up with is:

```
> foo$a[which(is.element(foo$b,c("A","E","C")))]
[1] 103 302 501
```

At which point I'm stuck, because while I've selected the correct rows, they aren't in the right order so I can't modify them individually.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Removing the `is.element` and use `%in%` is a solution if you don't care about matching order

[edit] - also can remove `which`

```
foo$a[foo$b %in% c("A","E", "C")]
```

Another possibility is to use `match` which will provide the indices of each element.

```
foo$a[match(c("A","E","C"),foo$b)]
[1] 500 100 300
```

Comment: You can drop `which` as well.

Comment: This doesn't seem to be working... `foo$a[foo$b %in% c("A","E","C")]` gives me `[1] 103 302 501`, as does `foo$a[which(foo$b %in% c("A","E","C"))]`

Comment: see my edit with `match`, I misunderstood your question.  I believe this should provide what you need.

Answer (score 1):

Is this something like this you want?

```
foo$a[match(c("A","E","C"),foo$b)]
```